# how to keep all created IDs in Postman Environment

Tags: json, api, automation, postman, environment

I am trying to automate API requests using `postman`. So first in POST request I wrote a test to store all created IDs in Environment : Which is passing correct.

```
var jsondata = JSON.parse(responseBody);  
tests["Status code is 201"] = responseCode.code === 201;  
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("BrandID", jsondata.brand_id);
```

Then in Delete request I call my Environment in my url like `/{{BrandID}}` but it is deleting only the last record. So my guess is that environment is keeping only the last ID? What must I do to keep all IDs?

Comment: Hello, how do you proceed ?
Do you call your POST request several times and then you call your DELETE request ? in that case, it is normal that you erase only the latest id that you set as, each time you call the POST request, you overwrite your environment variable.

Comment: Yes, I did exactly in that way, I call several times POST request and I think that all Ids must be stored in the Environment so after Delete it must erase all stored IDs. So do you have any idea how to proceed bulk delete with postman ? or how to store multiple IDs?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call your POST request, you overwrite your environment variable
So you can only delete the last one.
In order to process multiple ids, you shall build an array by adding new id at each call
You may proceed as follows in your POST request

```
my_array = postman.getEnvironmentVariable("BrandID");

if (my_array === undefined)    // first time
{
    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("BrandID", jsondata.brand_id); // creates your env var with first brand id
}
else
{
    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("BrandID", array + "," + jsondata.brand_id); // updates your env var with next brand id
}
```

You should end up having an environment variable like BrandId = "brand_id1, brand_id2, etc..."

Then when you delete it, you delete the complete array (but that depends on your delete API)
I guess there may be cleaner ways to do so, but I'm not an expert in Postman nor Javascript, though that should work (at least for the environment variable creation).

Alexandre